# directive with service not working, updated value is not shown on UI

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am trying to create a directive ('showLatestValue') which could be written as follows in HTML .

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8cohrm4/)

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <input type="button" value="Hit It" ng-click="SetIt()" />  
    </div>
   <show-latest-value></show-latest-value>
</div>
```

this directive will make use of a service. Following is the code I am experimenting with. I am not sure why the updated value is not shown when i click the button.

```
var myApp = angular
    .module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('testController',['$scope','latestValueService',function($scope,lvs){
        $scope.SetIt = function(){
            lvs.setValue('Updated Value');
        };
        $scope.firstName = "prerak";
    }]);

myApp.service('latestValueService', [function () {
        var latestValue = 'Init';
        this.setValue = function (newValue) {
            latestValue= newValue;
        }
        this.currentVal = function(){
            return latestValue;
        }
     }]);

myApp.directive('showLatestValue', ['latestValueService',function (lvs) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template:'<label>This is the current value {{valueRightNow}}</label>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.valueRightNow  = lvs.currentVal();
            }
        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because *you only get the value from the service **once** on the link function*. Then changes to this value will not be seen by the directive. You can set a $watch on the service value, and update `valueRightNow` accordingly:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return lvs.currentVal(); }, function(newVal) {
    scope.valueRightNow  = newVal;
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLnk89ck/).